# Изменение названий файлов

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом) Необходимо поменять имена в текущем каталоге на text(i) ну в зависимости сколько их.. просто если на один менять то они затираться будут!
Вот я написал что то похожее на код. Не могли бы вы мне помочь доделать его) Только важно не трогать тот файл где находится сам скрипт! это файл "xls" За помощь огромное спасибо)

```
ls | while read x
do
if [ $x != xls ] ; then

echo $x | grep '^[A-Z]'
echo $x | grep '^[a-z]'
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
y=`echo $x | sed 's/[A-Z]/text'`
y=`echo $x | sed 's/[a-z]/text'`
mv $x $y
fi
fi
done
```

Comment: Не понимаю, что на что Вы **хотите** поменять.

Сейчас Вы пишете, что *первую букву* в имени файла надо заменить на 'text'.

Например, Вы получите

    mv abc123 textbc123
    mv sbc123 textbc123
    mv dbc123 textbc123

Это то, что Вам действительно нужно? (файлы acb123 и sbc123 просто попадут).

Comment: я понимаю что беру 1 элемент и меняю только его. я просто не знаю как обращаться с помощью grep ко всему названию файла, что бы полностью его заменить и сделать text и допустим 1. как бы пронумеровать их.. в папке! Понимаю что код отстойный : ) по этому и прошу помочь)хотя бы как стереть полностью название заменить на text и прикрепить порядковый номер.. как это можно сделать?

Comment: Просто переименовать по индексу?

    I=1
    ls | while read x
    do
    if [ $x != xls ] ; then
    mv $x text$I
    I=$(($I+1))
    fi
    done

Comment: так просто это было.. не догадался! Сейчас проходим Bash.. и он мне не нравится вообще((...а когда желания нет и соображать не выходит... конечно логика не правильная) но что поделать((Благодарю!)) Спасибо большое за помощь!)

Comment: @smile573, проблема тут в том, что Вы просто на русском языке не можете написать, что именно хотите сделать.

Кстати, обычно в подобных скриптах вместо `ls | while read x` пишут

    for x in * 
    do
      case "$x" in
        xls)
          echo I am $0
        ;;
        *.sh)
          echo $x other shell
        ;;
        *)
          ....
        ;;
      esac 
    done

Это лучше, т.к. не используются только встроенные команды sh.

Comment: @smile573

      Сейчас проходим Bash.. и он мне не нравится вообще

Сочувствую, но предпочтения рекомендую менять.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

```
I=1
ls | while read x
do
  if [ $x != xls ] ; then
    mv $x text$I
    I=$(($I+1))
  fi
done
```